# Cassandra Select query returns allow filtering even if the column is in primary key

Tags: select, cassandra, primary-key, cql

I have created a orders table which is something like this

```
create_query1 = CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders
    (status text, city text, company text, country_id text, created_at timestamp,
    customer_address_id text, customer_id text, discount_amount float, discount_invoiced float, email text,
    entity_id text, firstname text, free_shipping float, grand_total_final float, is_qty_decimal float,
    is_virtual text, item_id text, lastname text, method text, name text, no_discount float,order_id text,
    original_price float, parent_id text, postcode text, price float, price_incl_tax float,
    product_id text, product_type text, qty_ordered float, qty_shipped float, quote_item_id text,PRIMARY KEY ((order_id), created_at ))
```

When I query something like

```
SELECT * from orders where created_at >= '2019-01-31 20:55:43' and created_at <= '2019-05-13 13:58:15'
```

I get this error

```
Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING"
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Is Cassandra not suited for this type of query?

Answer (score 1):

Query looks correct but you are using a different table name in query  than the one you created.

Comment: Opps Sorry, copied the wring query, 
I applied the query on the same table

Comment: Are you mentioning id in the query?Without id, it will need allow filtering since it is the partition key

Comment: No I'm not mentioning the id, I want to retrieve all the orders based on the date, 
what is the bets way to do this?

Comment: If the table size is small, you can add ALLOW FILTERING at the end of above query and it will work. Otherwise you need to change your primary key. You can create another column which will only store only the month and year of order like 09-2020.Replace this with order_id in primary key and include this column in where clause in query.So your primary key should look like primary key((newColumn),orderid,createdat)

Comment: but there will be plenty of orders in a month won't that affect since primary key should be unique?

Comment: new column will be just a partition key. the three columns will together form primary key, and since order id is part of overall primary key, it will be unique. You can get more info on keys here https://www.bmc.com/blogs/cassandra-clustering-columns-partition-composite-key/.

Comment: I did it and the query works well if the condition is = and it it doesn't if the condition is >= or <=

Comment: SELECT * from orders where year_month >= '01-2019' and year_month <= '05-2019'